# How to send object type parameter to GET type method in Rest web api using C# (API-ASP.NET MVC , Source ASP.NET C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a method of get type with class type parameter in web api (.NET MVC).Like below code

```
class Employee
{
   int Ind;
   int Empno;
}

[HttpGet]
public DataTable GetEmployee(Employee e)
{
   .............
   .............
   
   return new DataTable();
}
```

Below code I am using to call API:

```
internal DataTable CallApi()
{
     var client = new RestClient("......./Ctrl/GetEmployee");
     client.Timeout = -1;
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
     request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     Employee emp = new Employee()
     {
        Ind = 1,
        Empno = 10001
     };
     var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);
     request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
     IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

     Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(response.Content);
     return dt;
}
```

I want to call above API method from ASP.NET project, **Abobe code is hitting to api method**, But problem is that **Parameter that I am sending to call api  method is not getting in api method parameter**,

In objcet
Employee e , Parameter is not getting the sent objct.

Comment: @Luke That doesn't change the fact that `GET` requests generally don't have request-bodies, and while it _is_ supported by many systems, equally many systems in-between everyone else (think: web security firewalls, corporate stuff, etc) will complain: also, the latest HTTP spec implies it shouldn't be supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: I have also checked it :   ` GetEmployee([FromBody] Employee e)`   but I am getting same problem

Comment: ...why does an action named `GetEmployee` need an `Employee` DTO to be *passed-in*? That makes no sense...

Comment: @Dai you're right, I'm not fully awake

Comment: When I am calling API from Postman then working properly